# Why can't I access a function from a double (dot operators in C++)?

Tags: c++, object, oop, inheritance, methods

My task is to practice inheritance, putting all the classes in separate files. I have a base class `Circle` and a derived class `Cylinder`.

What I'm stuck on is trying to display on the screen the result of my calculated area and volume for an object `B` of a `Cylinder` type. I found a way to do that for a `Circle`, though it doesn't work for my `Cylinder`.

**circle.cpp**

```
#include "circle.h"
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

Circle Circle::area() {
    return M_PI * pow(r, 2);
}

void Circle::getArea() {
    cout << "Area = " << r << " m^2";
}
```

**cylinder.cpp**

```
#include "cylinder.h"
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


double Cylinder::area() {
    return 2 * M_PI * r * h;
}

void Cylinder::getArea() {
    cout << "Area = " << h;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "circle.h"
#include "cylinder.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Circle A;
    A.view();
    Circle A1(8);
    A1.view();
    
    Cylinder B;
    B.view();
    Cylinder B1(4, 6);
    B1.view();
    
    //A.area().getArea();
    //cout << endl;
        //A.circumference().getCircum();
        //cout << endl;
        //A1.area().getArea();
    //cout << endl;
        //A1.circumference().getCircum();
    
        B.area().getArea();

    return 0;
}
```

The error that I'm getting:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:26:14: error: request for member ‘getArea’ in ‘B.Cylinder::area()’, which is of non-class type ‘double’
   26 |     B.area().getArea();
      |              ^~~~~~~
```

I feel like neither my code in `main()` for instance `B`, nor my methods `getArea()` and `getVolume()` in class `Cylinder`, are correct. And there is probably a better approach to do the same for an object `A` and `A1` of a `Circle` type, though the code I commented out actually works.

Would be grateful for any advice on how I can fix this.

Comment: B.area() returns a double value, which does not have a member function of getArea(). You should try calling B.getArea(). You should look up how dot operators work.

Comment: `B::area()`  returns a `double`. `double` is not a type you can call `getArea()` on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `getArea()` function, instead of saying:

```
cout << "Area = " << endl;
```

Just say:

```
cout << "Area = " << area() << endl;
```

Then in your `main.cpp`, just call `B.getArea()`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Well, the reason you are getting the error message:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:26:14: error: request for member ‘getArea’ in ‘B.Cylinder::area()’, which is of non-class type ‘double’
   26 |     B.area().getArea();
      |              ^~~~~~~
```

Is because you are basically doing this:

```cpp
auto _ = B.area();
```

So here, `_` deduces to be a `double`, and then you do:

```cpp
_.getArea();
```

You are trying to access a member function from a `double`, and `double` doesn't have any member functions.

You probably meant to do this instead:

```cpp
auto x = B.area();
B.h = x;
B.GetArea();
```

This assigns the area of `B.area()` to a variable `x`, and assigns `x` to `B.h`. `B`'s member function then gets called and outputs the area.

Comment: Your Welcome, it was no proplem!